# Matlab SocketSever

Tags: matlab, serversocket

import java.net.Socket
import java.io.*

%# connect to server

I want to socket network in Matlab.

it worked well until yesterday but suddenly it doesn't work with error message..

```
while true

    fprintf('Server start...');


    sockets.client_socket = ServerSocket(6678);
    sockets.client_output = sockets.client_socket.accept;
    output_socket = sockets.client_output;

    ..............

end
```

error message =>

[ Undefined function or method 'ServerSocket' for input arguments of type 'double'.
  Error in ==> Con_sock at 19
    sockets.client_socket = ServerSocket(6678);]

How can i do? I tried to change 6678 data type to int8(), uint8() also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no ServerSocket function in Matlab so you are probably referring to an external class.

If you want to operate with sockets in Matlab, the proper way to do it is by using the `tcpip` funcion:

```
socket=tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server')
```

From there you can listen and receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need

```
import java.net.ServerSocket
```

before your code.